# Check If IP and URLs form list Exist

Tags: vb.net

Now i have:

```
Dim i As Integer  
  Dim web As New WebClient With {.Proxy = Nothing}
  'http://1.2.3.4/sql.db
   Dim attkstring As String = "/sql.db"
   i = 0
   Dim shellx As Integer = 0
   Dim sUrl As String = shells.Items(shellx) & attkstring
  For Each item In shells.Items
Try
    If web.OpenRead(sUrl) = True Then

    End If

Catch ex As Exception
End Try
  shellsloadedtext.Items.Add(sUrl)
  shellx += 1
Next
```

But in my ListBox write all (ip+url), I need to write the IP + the URL just in case work, and now writes them even if there are no

Ex: real ip: 7.7.7.7 false ip: 1.1.1.1

I write in the ip list 7.7.7.7 1.1.1.1

And my ListBox shellsloadedtext wirte 7.7.7.7/sql.db and 1.1.1.1/sql.db

Help me

Comment: On a side note, you probably meant `If web.OpenRead(item) = True Then`, otherwise your `sUrl` is constant value inside the loop, so the loop hardly makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Imports System.Net

Function UrlExists(destination As String) As Boolean

    Dim url As New Uri(destination)
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)

    Try
        Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse
            Return True
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: The OP is using HTTP request to check resource availability. You are suggesting to use ping. Do you know that most firewalls, especially in corporate networks, specifically block ping requests?

Comment: How can you say 'most' firewalls? have you worked at 'most' places? I am inside a corporate network now I can ping what I like - perhaps at a limited rate but nevertheless I can ping. Have worked at some very big places and never found that I couldn't ping, besides what's to say their paranoid admins aren't blocking many many more protocols other than the most basic ICMP? He made no mention of being behind a firewall so my answer stands. There are better ways to stop ddos than simply denying pings.

Comment: You just answered your question - you are **inside** a corporate network. [WAN ping blocking](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081122065427AA2vO5m) is used to conceal internal resources. It does not prevent DDOS, it's similar to a door that's closed. Most people won't bother trying a closed door, even if not locked. In any case, if OP is using HTTP, they may specifically want to be using HTTP. It's like "How do I drive a car?" , "Easily, get a bus!"

Comment: No it's not, it more like the OP asked - how do I drive an automobile. I answered with a steering wheel and you came back and said 'well actually I know of a car that uses a joystick so your answer is wrong'. It was a simple question, you are making massive assumptions based on no relevant information in the post.

Comment: You are being too aggressive right now. Instead, please take time to read the question title again, `Check If IP **and URLs** form list Exist`, how does ping help check the existance of the URL?

Comment: No i'm not it was no different to your previous comment, and thankfully you finally came back with an actual reason to change the answer. The ping works for IP addresses and base urls, but not for full urls. I have modified the code to suit.